Relation between Midrash Genesis Rabbah 51 and Targum Jerusalem Genesis 18:17
In Bereshit Rabbah 51 on Genesis 19:24 is found a very profound principle - whenever in the scripture is found "And the Lord, And the eternal" that means Hashem and his celestial court of justice. And Targum Jerusalem on Genesis 18:17 goes: "And the Lord with his Word said, Shall I hide from Abraham...".
Did the sages who wrote Targum Jerusalem keep in their minds this principle?

Can you provide the source please, I copied the link but couldn't understand what part you refer to.

As a rule, rabbinic principles stated in different sources (the Mishna, the Talmud, the Midrashim, etc) are not exhaustive and systematic. They didn't mean to account for all existing instances of a phenomenon they account for.

Welcome to the site. Are you sure sages authored this targum?

Welcome to MiYodeya and thanks for this first question. Since MY is different from other sites you might be used to, see here for a guide which might help understand the site. Great to have you learn with us!

Welcome to MiYodeya. It is always helpful in a question like this one to give the Hebrew text of the language quoted as well as the English translation. That helps to clarify the specific problem and will generally also provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need.

Like Harel13 I would query your premise that "the sages" were the authors of "Targum Jerusalem." As I understand it that targum is generally considered to have had a single author - see e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Targum_Pseudo-Jonathan just by way of example.

There are different opinions in Midrash. Happens all the time. If you see it one way in the Midrash Rabba and another in a Targum, then it simply reflects multiple valid opinions.
By the way, Onkelos' translation, especially, goes out of its way to avoid any sort of anthropomorphism or theologically-challenging statement. (For a more contemporary example, Rabbi Aryeh Kaplan's translation explains the figurative language as well -- what would literally in the Hebrew be G-d's "mighty hand" is "a show of great force", for example.)
